# Cotangent bundles of surfaces as varieties

Tags: complex-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, stein-manifolds

As far as I understand, it is easy to see (and find in the literature) that the affine variety
$$z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=1$$
with the restriction of the standard $\omega_{std}$ of $\mathbb{C}^3$ is symplectomorphic to $T^*S^2$ with the standard complex structure. Now, as mentioned here ([https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~markmclean/talks/cotangentaffine.pdf](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Emarkmclean/talks/cotangentaffine.pdf)), also $T^*T^2$ can also be written  explicitly as an affine variety. So my question is: Is there a general way to write $T^*\Sigma_g$ as the zero set of some polynomial in $\mathbb{C}^3$?

Comment: Seems that to get started one would need equations for $\Sigma_g$, see e.g., https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605734 then one would have an implicitization problem, see e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869303001819

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. As a complex variety, $T^*\Sigma _g$ can certainly not embed into $\mathbb{C}^3$, since it contains a copy of the compact variety $\Sigma _g$.

Comment: @abx: I think the question is about cotangent bundles with their canonical symplectic forms, for which the zero section is Lagrangian, and trying to find a compatible complex structure which makes the cotangent bundle an affine variety (i.e. a different complex structure to the one you have in mind).

Comment: @Jonny Evans: You are certainly right, thank you. The question might have been more explicit...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not possible. There is something called the growth rate of symplectic cohomology which is subexponential for affine varieties and exponential for cotangent bundles of higher genus surfaces (amongst other things). This was proved by McLean:

https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2542

Comment: It was actually proved by Totaro in the early 90s: https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S0129167X91000314. The key point is that the Hodge theory of the compactification should contain information of the "growth measure" of its affine piece.

Comment: @YHBKJ: Thanks! I didn't know this paper.